# How do i convert a JSON string to a native C# array using a namespace compatible with Windows Store Apps?

Tags: c#, php, arrays, json, windows-store-apps

I am trying to make a windows 8 Store app that gets results from a MySQL database from a PHP page as a REST service.

I'm looking for the PHP to return a JSON representation of an array of strings and have done that happily when dong the same between Javascript and PHP.
I need to take that same JSON string and use it in my C# Windows 8 store App, is there a way to take the return of that PHP page and convert it into a normal C# array, not a dictionary or more complex collection.

The database does have four fields so if i have to use a special object made for this i will, but I'd rather I didn't as this function doesn't require that amount of data.

The PHP page is like so - $search_text is passed in via a GET:

```
$databaseConnection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if ($databaseConnection->connect_error)
    {
        echo "Database connection failed: $databaseConnection->connect_error";
    }
    else
    {
        $search_text = $search_text."%";
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT street FROM gritroutes WHERE street LIKE ? LIMIT 5";
        $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('s', $search_text);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->store_result();
        $statement->bind_result($street);
        $autonumber = 1;
         while ($statement->fetch())
         {          
             $resultarr[] = $street;
         }
         $statement->close();
         echo json_encode($resultarr);
    }
```

Just to be clear. I am writing a Windows Store App, the System.Web Namespace is unavailable so i can't use JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: I've found Windows.Data.Json and the JsonValue Class, so i might be set, but i'm open for better suggestions, as i REALLY don't like the idea of an encapsulated array, especially as i'll be using nested arrays later in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add to Matthew's answer, you can deserialize using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) (you can get it from [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json)), you'd do something like:

```
List<string> myStrings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(myJson);
```

This is in:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Check out [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek4DeserializingJSONWithJsonNET.aspx) article for practical example.

**EDIT**
- I'd also like to throw in this [link](http://json2csharp.com/), since it's just awesome.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I second the json.net via nuget but also like to add that in the most recent tools update for visual studio you can simply right click in a class and paste json into a c# class format. That was available via Web Essentials previously but now is built in :)

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT - Woah ! Never knew that ! That's awesome !

Comment: Ah so there's one availible via NuGet, forgot about NuGet and that seems more suitable for what i want than Windows.Data.Json

Comment: Just tested it, beautiful, just what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class.

```
string myJson = "{blablabla I'm json}";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var myStrings = serializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(myJson);

foreach (var str in myString)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. The msdn definition kinda confused me as i was looking for a native array and just saw "object" which i didn't think i wanted. Totally forgot that i could use a list<string> for the same thing.

I was also under the impression that i'd have to do a lot more messing about to achieve what i wanted as all the other examples i'd found on stackexchange required custom objects.

Comment: Just tried this. Didn't work. Reason - I'm writing a windows store app. Not all namespaces are available, System.Web is one of the notable ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use native [`Windows.Data.Json`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229889.aspx) classes to do the parsing:

```
string json = @"[""item1"", ""item2"", ""item3""]";
var array = JsonArray.Parse(json).Select(i => i.GetString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: As i mentioned in my comment, i found this class just after i remembered that i couldn't get the System.Web solution. I was just fishing fro a better solution that didn't involve convoluted wrappers.